# MS SQL format calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have a computed column which is calculated this way:

```
(dateadd(month,[amorted_months],[real_date_start]))
```

The above stays in the Formula property of the column. This formula displays for example

'2013-02-28 10:22:15.583'

Now I want to format the column and to display only the date , not the time. When I use the FORMAT function like this:

```
(FORMAT(dateadd(month,[amorted_months],[real_date_start]), 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

It says that there's an error in validation the formula. I'm not good at SQL syntax and I suppose this is really stupid. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) instead like so:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
        dateadd(month,[amorted_months],[real_date_start]),
        121)
```

Comment: You missed the closing bracket for dateadd() but that solved the problem. Thanks.